# How to Preload video inside Animate CC

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas, jquery-animate, createjs

I'm trying to make my main timeline play on Animate once the video is loaded.

Here is how my code looks. Video loads but timeline doesn't play.

*this.stop();*

var video = document.getElementById("videoHTML");

var container = new createjs.Bitmap(video);

this.videoContainer.addChild(container);

var video = document.querySelector('video');

var root = this;
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {

init();

video.currentTime = 0.1;

root.gotoAndPlay(3);

}, false);